# Plugins for Crashlytics Tools for android studio

Tags: android, crashlytics

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.hunterdavis.com/2013/10/03/tutorial-crashlytics-android-studio-crash-reporting-on-easy-mode/) for Crashlytics in android studio.

But I am unable to get `Plugins for Crashlytics Tools for Android studio`.see this [image posted in that tutorial](http://www.hunterdavis.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/settings_plugin.png).But i cant find this.

My only problem is,I dont have plugins in my android studio for crashlytics tool.Where to get that.I am using updated android studio 1.2.1.1.

Anyone can help me with this.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might follow the wrong tutorial.

The official download and setting instruction page is as below
https://fabric.io/downloads/android-studio

The page will give you zip file immediately. Once you download it, then import zip file at the **Settings > Plugins > Install plugin from disk...** menu. Note that you don't have to unzip it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error today when missed to put into app level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

at the bottom